# Check if string contains word from badwortlist.txt

Tags: php

I have to use a badwordlist on a website. The bandwordlist.txt has arround 20.000 bad words in this format:

```
badword1 
badword2 
badword3
```

Every badword has a own line in the txt file.

What is the fastest way to check if a long string contains min. one of this 20k words.

I tried this without success. Of course I search stack before but couldnt find a solution:

```
$badwords = file('badwords.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);                

$words = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($words as $word) {
//Filter extraneous characters out of the word
$word = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/', '', $word);
//Check for bad word match
if (isset($badwords[$word])) {
    echo 'found';
exit;
}
}
```

thank you

Comment: What is `$trimmedfake`? // To get out of a foreach loop, you should rather use `break` than `exit`, the latter ends the whole script.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I changed it to $badwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
$badwords = file('badwords.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);                

$words = explode(' ', $string);
foreach($words as &$word) {
 //Check for bad word match
 if (in_array($word,$badwords)) {
    echo 'found';
    //if you want to remove word then do unset($word);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm :) - will give you the green arrow in 5 mins.

Comment: Loading the whole file into a memory seems a bit inefficient. If I was OP I would consider using a database for this.

Comment: @AlivetoDie  the bad word list is for a forum. I have to check every new post on the forum. Arround 2000 each day. The badword.txt has 143kb and 21323 Lines. Is it ok to use it as a textfile or do I get memory problems?

Comment: at the moment when the user press submit.

Comment: Import your txt file to database, then just send LIKE query to your db, it will be 100 times faster and use 100 times less memory...

Comment: Save all bad word in db and at the time data is coming use query tyo get all bad words and do rest of the code. Most efficient approach

Comment: last question: Do you mean the server memory? Will this memory want get free after the search?

Comment: Yes server memory. And yes it will be free

Comment: but when it will be free automaticly why do I get memory problems? I see the speedadvantage of sql but I tried to understand the memory isue. thanks

Comment: You can get memory problem at the time of fetching words from forum as you said that it's near about 2000 forums you searched for bad words.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I transformed the txt to the database. Made a select and have now an array of the bad words. It works but in_array works only with exact match. Is it possible to change the code above to a wildcard search? tx

Comment: You can use `strpos()` with loop. or `strtolower()` with `array_map()`. You can ask a new question regarding that and you will get answer for-sure. You can address me the link too (here in comment section) and if i will be free then i wll try to answer